# How to force a SageMaker Notebook instance to stop?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am an AWS noob, My notebook instance has been on **Pending Status** for a couple hours.

How can I force it to STOP ? Or at least get my code back.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried stopping it with the AWS CLI, i.e.

```
aws sagemaker stop-notebook-instance --notebook-instance-name myInstance
```

What does this return?

If the instance remains in the 'pending' state, please post a message in the AWS Forum for SageMaker, and Support should be able to help you: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=285